# Replacing Nested if Statement With AND

Tags: c#, nested-if

I am wondering whether nested if is better than AND statement. I have a loop that goes so many times so I am thinking of faster execution available. Below is the code that has same logic with my code. The nested if statement is inside a loop.

```
   for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   {
      // do stuff
      if (x == 5)
      {
         if (y == 3)
         {
             // do stuff
         }
      }
   }
```

Will my code be faster by a significant difference if I replace the nested if with this And STATEMENT?

```
     if ((x == 5) && (y == 3))
           // do stuff
```

I have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337037/replacing-nested-if-statements) but I didn't find the answer. I am a student and still learning, thanks for all the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET will stop checking if the first part of the conditional is false, so there will be no performance difference between the two.

Comment: does this logic happen in AND statement too?

Comment: That is what I meant. In the and statement, if the first half is false, it wont bother checking the second half.

Comment: That's called short circuiting, and all of the logical operators short circuit whenever possible, meaning if they know the result *must* be true/false they immediately stop executing any other statements since they can't affect the result.

Answer (score 9):

No, it will not have a significant difference on performance, *but* there may be a difference in readability.

Both of those will generate the same `IL` when compiled with optimization/release(Tested with LINQPad):

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_0004:  stloc.1     
IL_0005:  ldloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0007:  bne.un.s    IL_000D
IL_0009:  ldloc.1     
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_000B:  pop
```

Even without optimization the difference is not that significant:

**Nested statements:**

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_0005:  stloc.1     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0008:  ceq         
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000B:  ceq         
IL_000D:  stloc.2     
IL_000E:  ldloc.2     
IL_000F:  brtrue.s    IL_0020
IL_0011:  nop         
IL_0012:  ldloc.1     
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0014:  ceq         
IL_0016:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0017:  ceq         
IL_0019:  stloc.2     
IL_001A:  ldloc.2     
IL_001B:  brtrue.s    IL_001F
IL_001D:  nop         
IL_001E:  nop
```

**Not Nested statements:**

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_0005:  stloc.1     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0008:  bne.un.s    IL_0013
IL_000A:  ldloc.1     
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_000C:  ceq         
IL_000E:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000F:  ceq         
IL_0011:  br.s        IL_0014
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0014:  nop         
IL_0015:  stloc.2     
IL_0016:  ldloc.2     
IL_0017:  brtrue.s    IL_001B
IL_0019:  nop
```

Comment: @Almo, Having nested if-statements when you don't need to will cause everythign to be less readable, but that's subjective (maybe) :)

Comment: I agree with you, but the phrase "but on readability it" doesn't make any sense. It's ironic since it comments on readability, and is not itself readable. :)

Comment: @Almo, Hah, guess I have to blame it on not being a native speaker!

Comment: English might not be as tough as French to learn, but it's not easy, either. :)

Comment: They will be compiled to the same assembly (in this code), so there is no difference in all.

Comment: Added some `IL` code to show that there's no difference when compiled with release/optmization, but there is a difference when compiled without optmization/debug. Even without optimization the difference is not significant.

Answer (score 3):

No, there won't be any difference between the two. However, the AND makes fewer lines and is more readable (if you don't have that many conditions)

There are cases where `if`s are better and feel more natural, one common example is the following:

```
String s=//...
if(s==null)return;
if(s.Length > 0) //do something
```

With an AND, this can be replaced by:

```
if ((s!=null) && (s.Length > 0)) //Dosomething
```

Many developers do this mistake:

```
if ((s.Length > 0) && (s!=null) ) //Dosomething
```

Which will end up in a null reference exception

As you can see, it is more natural to think of doing the null check first when using separate `if`s

Answer (score 1):

In compiled code, there is no reason the speeds should be different, they will translate to exactly the same assembly code. I definitely agree about the readability factor, and it will shorten the length of your class as well.